# What is "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool"

Tags: debugging, interface-builder, crash, ios4

I got a code from a client to fix the bug (code was written by some other programmer), So when I open the xib file it simply hang my computer, i restarted my computer 3 times because of that and finally decided to see what's happening by opening the Activity Monitor and it turn out it is opening something with name "**Interface Builder Cocoa Touch tool**" and its eating all of my computer memory. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

But here is the interesting thing, it is not opening "**Interface Builder Cocoa Touch tool**" when open "xib" files from other projects, and i can't say anything about this project because this project has only one "nib" file.

But if kill that process, it open the nib file but an error start firing on me after every 10 sec. Below is the screen shot.

[image]

**Note:** App was written initially for ios 2.0 version and we are trying to move the project to ios 4.0. Is this thing has anything to do with this?

Comment: Can you get your client to convert the NIB from 2.0 to 4.0 for you? It sounds like the file got corrupted at some point.

Comment: @Kubi - I am not sure, i have to check if its possible, is there anyway i can convert it to newer version on my own?

Comment: It should work just fine on its own. Graham's answer is a good start for fixing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best course of action here is to create a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/, uploading your broken nib file as an enclosure. That doesn't get you working again, so try one of these:

- see if you can convince ibtool to write a working file, perhaps by doing some refactoring like changing one of the classes used then changing it back
- find out whether the client is on the same version of Xcode: if theirs is newer, upgrade
- use xmllint to see whether the xib is valid XML, and if not whether you can fix it in a text editor
- recreate the xib from scratch if it isn't too complicated