# why CPU is utilizing this much when I run xcode

Tags: ios7, xcode5, ibtool

Below is the screenshot of CPU utilization.

[image]

Just curious what are those `Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool` & `ibtoold` process.

Because of this, to run app, it takes me around 1 min least.

**Note:** I am using xcode 5

I see that this happens when there are more view controllers. I have around 25 view controllers.

---

Yes, I had created project in Xcode 4.6 and after updating, opened in Xcode 5.

**Attached is the screenshot for the file inspector.**

[image]

Comment: Is this really off-topic? "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow *unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming*.' -- seems legit to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a stack overflow question along similar lines but the question involved only a single nib. The project in that case was created for iOS2 and used a new version of Xcode. This led me to examine the latest Interface Builder Release Notes (3.2) which states:

> "Interface Builder documents can no longer be saved in the NIB 2.x
>   file format. NIB 2.x files will automatically be upgraded to NIB 3.x
>   files upon opening."

So, I would suggest you check the file inspector of your nib files and verify their current version. I suspect that Interface Builder is simply attempting to update 25 nib files to version 3.x. If you have an older Carbon nib files then please see the [Xcode Release Notes (v.4.0 - current)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/) as they require using version 3.2 in Xcode 4 and higher.

**Xcode 4.6.3 displays versioning of nibs on the file inspector using these menu items:**
[image: Xcode 4.6.3]

**While Xcode 5.0.1 displays versioning somewhat differently.**
[image: Xcode 5.0.1]

**The project document should also be in the latest format:**

[image: Project File Version].

The basic premise is that Xcode is converting the project file/nibs on load. If this recurs on every load I would report that as a bug to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com. I think the information found is pointing to the correct issue. Checking that the files are using the latest version should fix the issue unless there is a bug.

**Other things to try:**

- Load the project on a separate machine/directory (There might be some
  corruption on your current one)
- Run Console and [capture logs](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/mac/) as the problem is occurring (you will
  need to also capture system logs for Apple anyhow but the Console
  might show a useful error message)

References

- What is Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953500/what-is-interface-builder-cocoa-touch-tool).
- Xcode Release Notes (v. 4.0 - current), [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/).

Comment: attached is the screenshot,,,

Comment: @FahimParkar Updated answer with other things to try and project document check.